# Change color of bootstrap pager

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying change the color of a bootstrap pager.

All is working well, except, when I click on pager. After that, my pager color becomes gray.

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/wdjjqntu/2/  link to test.

What am I missing here?

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="next mypager"><a href="#">Voltar</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()  {
         $(document).on('click','.mypager', function()
              {
                 alert('ok');
              });
      });
</script>
```

css:

```
.pager .next > a, .pager .next > span { color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7; }
.pager .next > a:hover { color: #fff;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da; }
.pager .next > a.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #8c8c8c;
}
```

Comment: Change `.pager .next > a.focus` to `.pager .next > a:focus`

Comment: Marcelo, Thank you very much. It´s ok now.

Comment: Great! I would also close this question since it's unlikely to help any future readers.

Comment: Should I close or delete?. I ask you because I see no options  in close that sui, the reason for closing.

Comment: You can just delete it.